# Is there anyway to get total amount of a group client in specific topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's begin with understanding(cmiiw), A topic in kafka divided to partition each partition is consumed by clients in the same group. Which client consuming to which partition is depend on how many client available.

Example:
I got 3 client with same group "shipping'(lets say client A, B, C)

I got a topic called "verified" and having 4 partition(0,1,2,3)

Kafka will distributed those partition to each client like 0 - A, 1 - B, 2 - C, 3 - one of 3 clients.

Am I right till now?

Then my question is, is there anyway to find out how many client in the same group that consuming specific topic(in example above the total client is 3, i wanted to get number 3) ?

I'm just so lost, I am expecting a command to get number of clients consuming a specific topic

Comment: Did you mean to check which consumer in a group is consuming which partition?

Comment: Yes, that could help me

Comment: ok, in Java API (i.e. inside the consumer) or as command?

Comment: In the consumer, you can check via consumer.asssignment() to get a list of Topics and respective partitions.

Comment: I prefer use API shell

Comment: Adding my answer.

Comment: And btw, I use old kafka(which still using zookeeper)

Comment: Oh ok, which kafka version ? Let me know if the answer I provided doesn't work, I think in some older versions you need to pass --zookeeper instead of --bootstrap-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` tool to get details about the group, example which consumer is assigned which topic-partition.

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <host>:<port> --describe --group <group-id> --members
```

Ref:
https://supergloo.com/kafka-tutorials/kafka-consumer-groups-operations/

Also, Inside the consumer, you can check using `consumer.assignment()` to get a list of topics and partitions that the consumer is assigned.

Comment: @KevinJuniawan Oh, in that case now you have +10 :D